# How to make Brew install Vim with +clipboard?

Tags: vim, homebrew

I'm trying to figure out how to copy-and-paste between a file edited with Vim and the macOS Clipboard.  Most instructions say to start by installing Vim using Homebrew as it will be installed with the clipboard option enabled (vim --version will display "+clipboard").  However, when I installed Vim using brew, the clipboard option was still set to "-clipboard".  Can I force brew to reinstall Vim and turn this option on in the process?  I'm using Homebrew 1.1.2 which installed VIM 7.4.

Comment: It doesn't directly answer your question, but MacVim gives many benefits over terminal Vim, including native clipboard support, and is much nicer to work with in general.

Comment: Thanks.  Can I run MacVim from a remote Linux host via iTerm?

Comment: No. It's a standalone GUI program

Comment: Yea, then I can't use it.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Because Homebrew no longer takes package specific options on the command line you need to edit the formula to add support for the clipboard back and then tell brew to install from source and not from a bottle.

```
brew uninstall vim
brew edit vim
# Add `"--enable-clipboard",` after the `./configure` in the list of other options.
brew install -s vim
```

Summarized from this solution:
https://coderwall.com/p/avmotq/gain-clipboard-support-for-vim-on-os-x

Comment: :echo has('clipboard') in vim will return 1 if you did it right. I had to reload my shell.

Comment: `hash -r` should refresh the environment to make the new vim available to execute without needing to launch a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Andy Ray's comment…

MacVim is a GUI program but it also comes with a TUI executable that can be run in a terminal emulator. Because that TUI executable has all the features of the GUI program, installing MacVim is by far the easiest and safest way to have a full-featured *and* well optimized Vim on Mac OS X:

1. Download [the latest release](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases).
2. Mount the disk image.
3. Drag and drop MacVim.app to `/Applications/` or `~/Applications`.
4. Put the `mvim` script`somewhere in your`$PATH`.
5. [OPTIONAL] Add `alias vim='mvim -v'` to your shell's init script.

From your shell, you can do:

```
$ mvim foo.txt
```

to edit `foo.txt` in the MacVim GUI,

```
$ mvim -v bar.txt
```

to edit `bar.txt` in the MacVim TUI. Or, if you added the alias:

```
$ vim bar.txt
```

Now, to address your comment…

If you connect *to* your Mac *from* your Linux box, iTerm.app doesn't come into play and you can use whatever TUI program is installed on the Mac, including the Macvim TUI.

If you connect *to* your Linux box *from* your Mac, whether it is via iTerm.app or Terminal.app, the `vim` you are going to run will be the `vim` on your Linux machine so… what programs you install on your Mac doesn't matter at all as you won't have access to them anyway.

Comment: The poster specifically asked about installing vim via homebrew, not MacVim via an app.